# Postback Execution failed: (2031) No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mariadb

This is my postback.php code everytime showing

Execution failed: (2031) No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

I dont know where i am making mistake somebudy please help me
i allready searched but no solution found

```
define("MYSQL_HOST", "localhost");
define("MYSQL_PORT", "xxxx");
define("MYSQL_DB", "u530xxxx312_tap");
define("MYSQL_TABLE", "taxxx");
define("MYSQL_USER", "u5xxxx312_naxxxb");
define("MYSQL_PASS", "Mcxxxx455");

// Connecting to database, using MySqli
$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS, MYSQL_DB);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

// Setup postback variables
$uid            = $_POST['uid'];
$tid            = $_POST['tid'];
$cpid           = $_POST['cpid'];
$api_token      = $_POST['api_token'];
$payout_amount  = $_POST['payout_amount'];
$revenue        = $_POST['revenue'];

// Insert log into database
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".MYSQL_DB.".".MYSQL_TABLE." (uid, tid, cpid, api_token, payout_amount, revenue) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))) {
  echo "Preparation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $uid, $tid, $cpid, $api_token, $payout_amount, $revenue);

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
  echo "Execution failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
} else {
  printf("Added new conversion with uid: ".$uid." .\n");
}
```

Comment: Count your s's in the bind_param. 7 s's, 6 parameters.

Comment: Example am not good coder newbie pls sir

Comment: It's a simple typo. `bind_param('sssssss'` < you have 7 s's there. Only 6 question marks, and 6 variables being passed into bind_param. And not everyone on the internet is a sir.

Comment: Oh Thanks I Understand

Comment: now different error Execution failed: (1048) Column 'tid' cannot be null

Comment: Fairly self-explanatory. You're passing in an empty value in `$tid`. Validate/check your variables before you try to insert them. If something should not be empty, throw an error.

Comment: okay sir thank you very much i understand thanks again

Comment: You also have a code mistake: if the `prepare()` fails, you echo an error but still run the remaining lines of code. That will cause errors like `calling method bind_param on a boolean` because `$stmt` will be **false**, not an object. This is not causing the current error, but it might be a problem in the future.

Comment: Bill Karwin Sir please provide me solution am newbie pls sir